# Angular + Jasmine + Karma Test 'window.location.href'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've been pretty roadblocked on trying to figure out how to use Jasmine and Karma to test this piece of code. Essentially, I'm trying to write a test for when the user navigates back to the home page. Currently, when I run the test it opens the browser and gets stuck until I close the browser. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**component.ts**

```
  export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  goToHome(): void {
    window.location.href = '/';
  }
}
```

**component.spec.ts**

```
  describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  
  it('should call goToHome and navigate home', () => {
    component.goToHome();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, you don't want to use window.location to navigate to a page. You should use `router.navigate(['/'])`. This will first fix your Karma issue.

If your router is nested/complex please add more detail to your question.

Your test can assert that router.navigate was called, or you can use the `RouterTestingModule`.